# Page redirect on clicking of "Cancel" button of a confirm dialogue

Tags: javascript, html, forms, confirm

Please look at the code snippet -

```
<form action="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are You Sure?')">
       <a id="saveBtn" class="btnClass">Save<a/>
</form>
```

When I click on the 'Save' and then Click on the "**Ok**" button of confirm popup the form get submitted. If I click "**Cancel**" the form is not submitted and the I left on the current page. Is it possible if I click "**Cancel**" button then the page redirected to other page?

Comment: yeah, handle the response in an own function and to the redirect manually. As long as you return true or false from your own function you wouldn't really change the behavior

Comment: Just add an eventlistener on the cancel button.

Comment: @K.Daniek I think he means  the standard dialogbox that pops up on confirm

Comment: @Icepickle Even if so, isn't it possible to add eventlistener on the button inside popup window?

Comment: No, it stops the execution of the current code, till the user does something and returns true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not use the `onsubmit` attribute, go with the unobtrusive event listener approach for better readability and maintainability.

Something like this should show the general idea and you can update it with your own redirect link:

```
var submitLink = document.getElementById('saveBtn'),
    myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

submitLink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (confirm('Are You Sure?')) {
        myForm.submit();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = 'http://google.com'; // redirect to your own URL here
    }
});
```

This relies on the form and anchor having `id` attributes:

```
<form action="post" id="myForm">
   <a href="#" id="saveBtn" class="btnClass">Save<a/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the confirm dialog by equating the state to true or false.

```
function myFunction() {
 var r = confirm('Are You Sure?');
 if(r==true) 
 return true;
 else {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location="http://example.com";
 }
}
```

Here is a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/BoyWithSilverWings/p7knLr3m/

Comment: Your code has a few minor points, nl, non strict checking of true and event coming out of nowhere, your fiddle doesn't really does return true (which is okay since it will send it anyhow), but it can be written lots nicer  (and if you are using onsubmit, then it should state onsubmit="return myFunction()" so you can cancel it with returning false (or why not simply return r). Naming is something that is a bit hard at first but it makes your code so much clearer

Comment: Will take care of that next time. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can because the confirm will return true/false you can code additional behavior for false result, an example is:

```
<form action="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Are You Sure?')? true:window.location.assign('http://www.w3schools.com')">
   <a id="saveBtn" class="btnClass">Save<a/>
```

Comment: Add event.preventDefault() to the code, otherwise the form will be submitted either-case.